# Should I use an apostrophe, when the possession appears before the possessive subject?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

In the following (poorly written?) sentence:

> You improve your co-worker's luck and your **business's**.

I want to say that the luck of your business will also be improved... **How do I say this? By putting an apostrophe after "business"?** I'm trying not to repeat "luck".

Comment: The possessive form of *business* is *business’s*.  You cannot just put a lone apostrophe there, because that is not how it is pronounced.

Comment: @tchrist: Edited my question. The thing is: if I had used "business's" would the sentence be correct?

Comment: Sure, it would have been fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In speech, I think I would say ***and your business's***, pronounced *-nisiz*. In writing, I would change it to ***and that of your business***.

Comment: Why business's and not business' ? Is it because business is an irregular word?

Comment: @JohnAssymptoth No, it is completely regular. It’s because *business’s* is pronounced with an extra syllable compared with *business* alone.  I don’t understand why this spelling mistake is so common. You only use a single apostrophe when there is no change in pronunciation when forming the possessive, like with *this species’ strategy* or *those farmers’ fields*. That’s why it is the *class’s president*, or perhaps just the *class president*, but never the **class’ president*, which makes no sense.

Comment: @tchrist: I agree that this is the best rule and that it is often recommended by style books; but I think some people use or have used to use other rules as well.